# data's are not saving in database

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am using the following code in views.py

```
def when(request):
    log.debug("test....")

    reportform = ReportForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if reportform.is_valid():
            log.debug("test:%s",reportform)
            reportform = reportform.save()

    return render_to_response('incident/when.html',{'newreport_menu': True,
    'form': reportform },context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

my template is

```
{{ form.manual_date_time }}

    <p id=ir-nextbutn><a href="{% url incident.views.media %}"> 
    <form action="/member/media/" method="POST"> {% csrf_token %}
    {% include "buttons/next.html" %}
      </form>
```

models.py

```
class Report(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=False)
    incident_number = models.CharField('Incident Number', max_length=100)
    device_id = models.CharField('Device Id', max_length=100)
    app_uuid = models.CharField('Unique App Id', max_length=100)
    created_date_time = models.DateTimeField('Created')
    manual_date_time = models.DateTimeField('Another time', null=True, blank=True)
    sent_date_time = models.DateTimeField('Sent')
    incident_description = models.TextField('Incident description', null=True, blank=True)
```

Here i am saving the date time field in database.After entering the time and date in the field if the user clicks the next button save and goes to next page.But it is not storing the data.I am using MySql db.

Comment: is the form definitely valid?  Add an `else` and take a look at `reportform.errors`

Comment: one more thing,since i am changing the existing website,the data's like user,incident_number,device_id are not generated automatically.My idea is to pass that value in form explicitly.How to explicitly pass value to form

Comment: You instatiate an empty form. You should do `ReportForm(request.POST)` after the `if request.method == 'POST':`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not applying any data to the form so it cannot be vaild.

```
def when(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Form with POST'ed data
        reportform = ReportForm(
            data=request.POST,
        )

        if reportform.is_valid():
            log.debug("test:%s",reportform)
            reportform = reportform.save()
            # You should redirect to a different page at this point
            # This will avoid double POST'ing and saving
            redirect_to = request.POST.get(
                'next',
                reverse('name-of-url-defined-in-your-urls.py')
            )
            return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_to)
        else:
            # Check the errors, they *should* appear when the form is rendered
            pass
    else:
        # Blank form, no data
        reportform = ReportForm()

    return render_to_response(
        'incident/when.html',
        {
            'newreport_menu': True, 
            'form': reportform,
        },
        context_instance=RequestContext(request)
    )
```

**UPDATE:**

Additionally your form is not encompassed within the `form` tags.  And your "next" button needs to be an `input` or `button` with `type="submit"`

```
<form action="/member/media/" method="POST"> {% csrf_token %}
    <input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ url_to_redirect_to }}"/>
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" name="save" value="save"/>
        OR
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

**Side note:**

You could probably add `auto_now_add=True` to the `created_date_time` to avoid you having to set it yourself and also stop it being edited and appearing in `ModelForm`s

```
created_date_time = models.DateTimeField('Created', auto_now_add=True,)
```

Comment: Hi sir,after entering data in the field if i press next button it should redirect to next page,same time the data entered should save in database.

Comment: Your form is not within the `form` tags so the data will not be POSTed

Comment: next button is of type submit,i am maintaining in separate html.Instead of setting a separate save button,how to use next button for save and navigate to next page.

Comment: (Updated answer).  You could add a next `input type="hidden"` to the form.  Then in your view check if it exists and redirect to that url.

Comment: You can simply do this `next_url = request.POST.get('next', reverse('name-of-url'))` instead of your `if` condition.

Comment: Good point @BurhanKhalid, updated accordingly.  I could actually put it directly into the `HttpResponseRedirect()` but will avoid nesting too many things

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not entirely sure what you mean, could you either update the question or preferably ask a second question as it sounds like a separate problem.  It may be covred by `commit=False` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method), initial values (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#providing-initial-values) or even excluding fields in the `ModelForm` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-a-subset-of-fields-on-the-form).

Comment: Let me tell my doubt,in models.py above fields are user-->foreign key,incident_number,device_id are fields without data.Since i am making changes in old wensite.Now i am leaving blank that fields and entering the date time field which is the only field available in this page.Is that the matter it is not saving in the database even after using your codes

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are not populating the user field in the form. The Report model has user as a non null foreign key so that's probably giving you trouble. You need to explicitly add the
fields that the form does not populate and then save:

```
if reportform.is_valid():
    log.debug("test:%s",reportform)
    report = reportform.save(commit=False)
    report.user = request.user  #assuming a login_required decorator
    report.incident_number = ...
    ....
    report.save()
```

so we create the report object from the form with the fields that the form supplies. Since the report object is still incomplete, we do not commit now. Then we add the remaining fields and save.

Comment: have 1 doubt,should i assign report.incident_number=request.user

Comment: that means,i dont want to give report.incident_number and device_id and so on right